# Multiple many-to-one joins on same column erroneously results in SELECT being performed

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a class which looks like this:

```
[Class(Table = "SessionReportSummaries", Mutable = false)]
public class SessionReportSummaries
{        
    [ManyToOne(Column = "ClientId", Fetch = FetchMode.Join)]
    public Client Client { get; private set; }

    [ManyToOne(Column = "ClientId", Fetch = FetchMode.Join)]
    public ClientReportSummary ClientReportSummary { get; private set; }
}
```

The SessionReportSummaries view has a ClientId column, and I’m trying to join both a Client object and a ClientReportSummary object using this column.

Unfortunately, NHibernate only wants to join the first one defined in the class, and always performs a SELECT for the second one. So in this scenario NHibernate queries the database first with:

```
SELECT {stuff} FROM SessionReportSummaries ... left outer join Clients on this.ClientId=Clients.Id ...
```

(with lots of other joins), and then N of these:

```
SELECT {stuff} FROM ClientReportSummary WHERE ClientReportSummary.ClientId = '{id goes here}'
```

one for each of the N clients in question. This results in terrible performance.

If I swap the positions of the Client and ClientReportSummary objects then NHibernate instead joins ClientReportSummary onto the SessionReportSummaries object, and performs a select for each Client object.

Does anyone know how I can get NHibernate to perform a join for both of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate will take only one **same column** mapping in a single query. So, because there are two different entities mapped via column attribute to value "ClientId":

- [ManyToOne(Column = "ClientId", Fetch = FetchMode.Join)]
- [ManyToOne(Column = "ClientId", Fetch = FetchMode.Join)]

The uniqueness of column mapping is in this case not granted. And it could cause damage, when insert or update form both entities would be applied. But we can use a trick: `FORMULA` mapping

```
[Class(Table = "SessionReportSummaries", Mutable = false)]
public class SessionReportSummaries
{        
    [ManyToOne(Column = "ClientId", Fetch = FetchMode.Join)]
    public Client Client { get; private set; }

    [ManyToOne(Formula = "ClientId", Fetch = FetchMode.Join)]
    public ClientReportSummary ClientReportSummary { get; private set; }
}
```

Now NHibernate will take one colum mapping as real relation and evaluate the second (defined in `formula`) as a different one. Now single select statement will be used

Whenever `formula` is used for mapping (instead of `column`), it should be marked as `insert="false"` and `update="false"`. We need it just for a SELECT. (otherwise we can append a Client and a ClientReportSummary with different ClientId to SessionReportSummaries entity - which will violate exception...

*The second approach could be one-to-one mapping, where the "ClientId" is expected to be really the same in all three tables... but it is another topic*

Comment: Excellent -- that did the trick. I believe that **insert="false"** **and update="false"** shouldn't be required as the class is marked as immutable, correct?

Comment: Good note! To be honest I am not sure;), I would always prefer to explicitly mark in code what is important, that it was my intention. It will improve readability and make maintainance more easy...